# Talend 8.0.3 - Component tDBSCD (MSSQL/MySQL)

Tags: talend

I'm currently learning the SCD methodology and tried to apply it with Talend (TOS 8.0.3 for DI) and I noticed something with the tDBSCD component. I tried using the tDBSCD with 2 different databases, one with MySQL and the other one with SQLServer.

[image]

So the issue I have is when using the tDBSCD component with the MySQL database (configuration) I have the option "Action on table" but not when I configure it for MSSQL.

[image]

Is the "Action on table" option (for tDBSCD component) only available for MySQL (and possibly other databases, I didn't check them all) and if you know why ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the documentation option to figure out the answer?

Comment: Yes I checked the Talend documentation, and I saw that this feature is only available for some like MySQL and Oracle but isn't for others like PostgreSQL and MSSQL, but there is no explanation for the why.

Comment: Only Talend developers can tell you why.

Comment: Are you sure its 8.0.3 because as far as I know there was only an 8.0.1 for TOS. https://github.com/Talend/releases  (Enterprise does receive monthly patches but that's still 8.0.1 R2022-09 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually compare the 2 components:
MySQL:
https://github.com/Talend/tdi-studio-se/tree/master/main/plugins/org.talend.designer.components.localprovider/components/tMysqlSCD

MsSQL: https://github.com/Talend/tdi-studio-se/tree/master/main/plugins/org.talend.designer.components.localprovider/components/tMSSqlSCD

You can see that MySQL has a TABLE_ACTION entry: https://github.com/Talend/tdi-studio-se/blob/master/main/plugins/org.talend.designer.components.localprovider/components/tMysqlSCD/tMysqlSCD_java.xml#L154

And the code generation also includes the tableAction snippet: https://github.com/Talend/tdi-studio-se/blob/master/main/plugins/org.talend.designer.components.localprovider/components/tMysqlSCD/tMysqlSCD_begin.javajet#L113

SQL server doesn't have the UI element defined neither it includes the tableAction snippet, that's the reason it's not visible.

If you look at the snippet you can see it only covers MySQL and Oracle.
https://github.com/Talend/tdi-studio-se/blob/master/main/plugins/org.talend.designer.components.localprovider/components/templates/_tableActionForSCD.javajet

With that being said there's a tCreateTable component that you could use with your schema to create tables.